# var module = require() or const {module} = require()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, require

Whats the diference between this two require methods:

```
1. var xx = require('module')
2. const {xx} = require('module')
```

I saw the first onde I can access xx as variable, with all script exported by module.. and second xx are undefined. How to access second "method" or is it a method too construct module to use {}

thanks

Comment: do `const xx = require('module');`. What you are doing is getting the `xx` field of the module. `const {xx} = require('module');` is the same as `const xx = require('module').xx`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first puts the full module handle in a variable named `xx`.

The second gets the `xx` property from the module handle and puts it in a variable named `xx`.   So, the second would be the same as:

```
const xx = require('module').xx;
```

Also the first is using `var` and the second is using `const`, but I assume you already knew about that difference.

---

Said a different way:

This:

```
const {xx} = require('module');
```

is a shortcut for this:

```
const xx = require('module').xx;
```

It's most useful as a shortcut when using `require()`, when you want to get a bunch of properties from the module and assign them all to top level variables in your module like this:

```
const {xx, yy, zz, aa, bb, cc} = require('module');
```

which would obviously take a lot more code to replicate than that single line if you weren't using the object destructuring syntax.

FYI, all of this is just a form of **object destructuring** (a feature added to Javascript in ES6).  It's not anything specific for `require()`, it's just that `require()` often returns an object with a bunch of properties that one is interested in.  See this article ["A Dead Simple into to Destructuring"](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/) for a nice summary of what object destructuring does.

Comment: Nice !!! 

It's means, if I try to use "const {ricardo} = require('express')" console.log(ricardo) will be undefined because there are no class "ricardo" inside express.

And If a make a file "modal.js" = 
class test {
}
exports.test = test;

and a "test.js" = 
const { test } = require("./modal.js")
console.log(test)

it's return [Function: test] !!

Very well explained !! Thanks !!

Comment: @RicaGurgel - Yep, it seems like you understand it now.  I'd suggest reading about object destructuring in general since it's a language feature that is useful in many other contexts too.

Comment: yes! got the link!! reading "object destructuring" and testing everything ! Very thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's cause your module is export as a object with out method xxx.
Example:

```
module.exports ={abc : ()=>{}}
```

1. var xx = require('module') , you can call function abc by : xxx.abc()
2. you only call abc by const {abc} = require('module')
   You can't call xxx in case 2 because there is no method with name xxx

Answer (score 0):

These two differ in two aspects:

1. Constness of `xx`: in the first case, adding the statement `xx = 5;` is legal, but not in the second case, since you declared xx as const.
2. In the second example, you use destructuring. Destructuring takes elements from objects and assigns them directly to variables. For instance:

```
var a = { "x": 1, "y": 2};

var { y } = a;
// This is equivalent to:
var y = a.y;
```

Then your second statement just takes the `xx` attribute from your module as if you did:

```
const xx = require('module').xx;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. var xx = require('module')
2. const {xx} = require('module')
```

First, `var` is a variable type whose value can be modified after defined; the `const` value cannot be modified after defined.

Second, `var xx` is referring to the main export of `module`; `const { xx }` is referring to a property of `module`'s export.

---

**Example 1. Module**

```
const xx = {}
module.exports = xx
```

**Example 2. Module**

```
const xx = {}
const yy = {}
module.exports = {
  xx,
  yy,
}
```

Otherwise...

---

**Example 1. Module**

```
const xx = {}
export default xx
```

---

**Example 2. Module**

```
const xx = {}
const yy = {}
export default {
  xx,
  yy,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `var xx = require('module');` mean you **import the whole 'module'** and put it into **xx** variable.
2. `var {xx} = require('module');` mean you **import the 'module' 's one porperty/object** and put it into **xx** variable.

Other way to write 2 is `var xx=require('module').xx`.