# Error saying that my function is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I'm coding a bot of discord in node.js, specifically, a economy bot for private use. My problem is that I get "is not a function" error that appears when I try to execute a command which calls a function, which is declared and exported in another file. I'll let you 2 scripts so you can see better.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const ecoSchema = require('../modelos/profileSchema');
const { saveCurrencyData } = require('../handlers/funcion');


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('money')
    .setDescription('Da dinero gratis!'),

    name: 'money',
    run: async(client, interaction) => {
        await saveCurrencyData(interaction.user.id)
        await ecoSchema.findOneAndUpdate({ UserID: interaction.user.id }, { $inc: {banco: 100}});
        interaction.reply({ content: `100$ han sido añadidos a tu cuenta`})
        return this.data
    }
}
```

Here I declare and export the command, in this case "money, the one access the basedata, first executing the "saveCurrentlyData" function which identifies or, in case that the user doesn't have a schema made for him, it creates it. Then, it increases the money value for 100$.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    ]
})
const {data} = require('./comandos/dinero');

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'money') {
        const increase = await data(client, interaction)// (En "await es donde marca el error)
    }
});
```

This is the piece of code which executes the command, and is placed in the index.js file. Here is where the error points at, showing that "data" is not a function. Error output:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: data.data is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lazar\Desktop\Bot banco\index.js:33:31)
```

I've tried as well writing data.data() but it doesn't work anyway, bringing the same error. I don't know why it doesn't get it as a function and, I'd appreciate if someone could help me fixing this.

Comment: You want to use `run` not `data`

Comment: `data` is an instance of `SlashCommandBuilder`, not a function; as such it's not callable. Looks like you should instead be writing `await run(...)`.

Comment: Even if I use `run()` I get another error: `ReferenceError: run is not defined`

Comment: You're only importing `data`, so either import all under a token (`const command = require('./comandos/dinero')` and use `command.run()`, or add `run` to the import: `const { data, run } = require('./comandos/dinero')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a simple problem from a bad import.

You're trying to import your command with the line
`const {data} = require('./comandos/dinero');`, but this isn't correct.
Essentially, you're just importing `data` (The slash command builder), so you're trying to run the information about the slash command like a function when it isn't.

What you'll want to do is import the *entire* command object with `const dinero = require('./comandos/dinero');`, then run the command with `dinero.run(client, interaction)`.

Once you do that, your code should look something like this:

```
const dinero = require('./comandos/dinero'); // Import the entire object

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'money') {
        // Run the exec function rather than trying to run dinero.data like a function.
        const increase = await dinero.exec(client, interaction)
    }
});
```

I've made mistakes like this before; make sure to look into what `const { ... } = require(...)` does. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250163/var-module-require-or-const-module-require) Stack Overflow issue explains it pretty well!